# Eager loading association scope returning empty array in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model, an association, and a scope like so:

```
class Job

  has_many :items

  scope :current_items, -> {includes(:items).where("items.start_at = ?", start_at).references(:items)}

end
```

And I'm calling the scope like so:

```
Job.current_items.where(....)
```

Instead of returning a collection of Jobs and eager loaded items with conditions regardless of whether the items exist, the call above is returning an empty array []. How do I eager load items with conditions?

Answer (score 0):

For your use-case this will perform the same:

```
class Job
  has_many :items
  scope :current_items, -> { joins(:items).where(items: { start_at: start_at }) }
end
```

When you perform `Job.current_items.where(...)`, a separate query is created and your eager loaded association is not used, because Rails cannot transform that SQL where clause into some sort of an in-memory query returning eager-loaded association.

You will have to move that `where(...)` before you eager load the association.

Comment: hmm. Doesnt work. PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause